# Cant find image by path in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, file, path

Can't share image knowing its path. I call this function with "images/image.png" and get:
**Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(images/baws.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), null, null, null)**

```
shareImage(BuildContext context, String imagePath) async {
    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
    await Share.file('Essi', imagePath, bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'images/png');
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: where is the image path coming from?

Comment: I change a variable depending on what image the user clicks. It has a format of "images/image" and it works fine with the Image widget.

Comment: is the image coming from assets  or on device ?

Comment: It is coming from assets

Comment: i dont this is possible

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the images directory to your pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
    # path to image dir
    - assets/images/
```

make sure you did `flutter pub get`

if you already did that, try  relaunching your app.

if none that worked, we'll be needing more info to be able to debug

Comment: I did that. If I want to use image1, I can use images/image1 as a path but if I want to use it with the share plugin it tells me it can't find the file.